# Why didn't Moe recognize Bailey (aka Max) In Once Upon A Time In America?

Tags: once-upon-a-time-in-america, sergio-leone

Let's pretend that it's not a dream. I figured old Moe would have been watching the news at the diner/bar, at some point one night, and seen Bailey's picture on screen, since he was now a high-profile person; and at least mentioned it to Noodles ("yeah, terrible stuff, and you know that Bailey guy looks kinda like Max... did he have a brother?") that there was at least a little resemblance when they were watching together once he got back into town. I figured he'd remember him since he spent his first 30 years around him and ran the speakeasy!
Thoughts/Theories?

Comment: I think Moe definitely recognized him. The question is why didn't he tell Noodles.

Comment: Moe might have simply assumed it's someone shockingly similar and that's all, especially as it was probably a few years since the 'death' of Max and his reemerging as a known person, so he aged a little. What was more surprising to me is that Max had a son with Moe's sister and there was absolutely no chance Moe wouldn't have realised who Bailey was at that point. All that of course if we assume that it all really happened and wasn't just Noodles' dream, where everything would be possible and everything would make sense.